# How to query rails way ? Rails 3.2

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

List of relationship between models:

```
class ErrorScope  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :server
  has_many :scope_to_fixflow_map
  attr_accessible :id, :server_id, :error_codes, :scoping_method, :priority, :error_codes_is_wildcard_match
  serialize :error_codes
  .....
end

class ScopeToFixflowMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :error_scope
  attr_accessible :id, :server_id, :error_scope_id, :path, :fixflow_class_name
  ......
end

class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :error_scopes 
  ......
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "error_scopes", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "server_id",                     :limit => 8,                    :null => false
    t.text    "error_codes",                                                   :null => false
    t.text    "scoping_method"
    t.integer "priority",                                                      :null => false
    t.boolean "error_codes_is_wildcard_match",              :default => false
  end

  create_table "scope_to_fixflow_maps", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "server_id",          :limit => 8, :null => false
    t.integer "error_scope_id",     :limit => 8, :null => false
    t.string  "path"
    t.string  "fixflow_class_name",              :null => false
  end
```

Now i have a sql query which gives me desired output:

```
SELECT fixflow_class_name 
FROM error_scopes s
join scope_to_fixflow_maps m on s.id=m.error_scope_id
join servers serv on serv.id=s.server_id
where error_codes regexp 'error_scope_test'
and path = 'x'
and assettag = 'y'
```

What I tried so far. It works

```
ErrorScope.where("error_codes like ?", "%error_scope_test\n%").select {|tag| tag.server.assettag == "y"}[0].scope_to_fixflow_map.select {|y| y.path == "x"}[0].fixflow_class_name
```

using joins

```
ErrorScope.joins(:server, :scope_to_fixflow_map).where("error_codes LIKE ?", "%error_scope_test%").select {|tag| tag.server.assettag == "y"}[0].scope_to_fixflow_map.select {|y| y.path == "x"}[0].fixflow_class_name
```

I am sure there must be better way to do this query??

Comment: It's unclear from your SQL which tables the various columns you're referencing are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ErrorScope.joins(:server, :scope_to_fixflow_map)
.where("error_codes LIKE ?", "%error_scope_test%") 
.where("servers.assettag='y'")
.where("scope_to_fixflow_maps.path='x'")
.select("scope_to_fixflow_maps.fixflow_class_name")
```

Comment: `ErrorScope.joins(:server, :scope_to_fixflow_map).where("error_codes LIKE ?", "%error_scope_test%")` this works good. when i chain with this `.where("server.assettag='y'")` gives me error.
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'server.assettag' in 'where clause':`

Comment: @Kavincat Yeah, should have been `servers` & `scope_to_fixflow_maps` instead of `server` & `scope_to_fixflow_map` respectively. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the rails way but quick and dirty:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.execute("SELECT fixflow_class_name 
FROM error_scopes s
join scope_to_fixflow_maps m on s.id=m.error_scope_id
join servers serv on serv.id=s.server_id
where error_codes regexp 'error_scope_test'
and path = 'x'
and assettag = 'y'")
```

Returns back an array of hashes that you can work with